# Extract Filenames from a list of files including Full-Path in Notepad++

Tags: regex, path, notepad++, extract, filenames

I have a list containing thousonds of files in a text file like this:

```
C:\AAAA\BBB\CCC\file1.dat
D:\AAAA\FF FF F\CCC\file 2.dat
D:\ANN NN\BBB\CCC\The.Third.File.dat
```

and I want to keep just the filenames like this:

```
file1
file 2
The.Third.File
```

How can I do it? Maybe someone can do it with RegEx?

I can do it in Delphi (the language I master) like this:

```
var
  St: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  st := TStringList.Create;
  try
    st.LoadFromFile('F:\TheFile.txt');
    for i := 0 to st.Count - 1 do
      st[i] := ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(st[i]), '');
    st.SaveToFile('F:\TheFile.txt');
  finally
    st.Free;
  end;
end;
```

but I want to learn it in NotePad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use search and replace in *Notepad++* with this as search field:

```
^.*\\
```

And set an empty replace value.

Then choose **regular expression** and don't check the option for `.` matching new lines.

Explained and testable here: https://regex101.com/r/8Fp6E6/1

- `^` asserts position at start of a line.
- `.` matches any character (except for line terminators).
- `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- `\\` matches the character `\`.

As you can see the idea is to get rid of the path before the file name.
We take advantage of the fact that by default the `.*` matches anything until a `\` char but by beeing greedy so continuing until it can. The ungreedy pattern would by `^.*?\\` and in this case it would get rid of the drive and first backslash only.

If you want to search for the files only by doing it by searching for anything which isn't a backslash and followed by the end of the line then you could search for this:

```
[^\\]+$
```

Explained:

- `[^ ... ]` matches any char which isn't in the given list (...).
- So `[^\\]` matches any char which isn't a backslash.
- `+` matches the previous token one or several times. It's similar to
  `*` but we don't want to match zero times so this is why we use `+`
  instead of `*`.
- `$` matches the end of the line.

#### Second question to also remove the file extension

To remove the path and the extension in the same time, you'll have to
match the full line and capture the part you want (the filename
without the extension) with some parenthesis and use the captured
content as replacement. Search pattern:

```
^.*\\([^\\]+?)(?:\.\w+)?$
```

Replacement field: `$1` *(= capturing group number 1)*

Explained:

- `^.*\\` matches the path, as before.
- `([^\\]+?)` will capture the filename part in an ungreedy way.
- `(?:\.\w+)?$` will match the dot and the file extension if it exists:

  - `\.` matches the dot character.
  - `\w` matches any word char and is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.
  - `(?:  )` is a non-capturing group. We use it because we want to
    say that the file extension is optional with a question mark after
    it: `(?:\.\w+)?`.
  - `$` matches the end of the line.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/wvDjAJ/2

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. And how to delete the extension?

Comment: I've added an explanation on how to match the files only. So try to find how to match the extension only. To match the `.` char you have to escape it if not it will have the meaning "any char". This is simply done with the backslash so it would be `\.`.

Comment: If you want to do both operations in one search and replace then search for `^.*\\([^\\]+)\.\w+$` and replace by `$1` (to replace by the first capturing group which is delimited by parentheses). See it working live with the explanation: https://regex101.com/r/wvDjAJ/1

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't answer you sooner. Thanks. That's wonderful and works fine.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted just because you answered my question sooner, but the "The fourth bird"'s answer was also good. Again excuse me that I answered and accepted late because yesterday I had to leave my working place and did't have access to my account.

Comment: I'm sorry @Mahan! I have so many times helped persons that didn't answer anymore that I thought *"it's arriving again..."*. I tried to give a non-complex answer to your question as you probably are just starting to play with the power of regular expressions. They are so useful that I often think *"but why didn't I know how to use them 15 years ago!"*. Thanks for your nice feedback!

Answer (score 1):

To keep the filenames after the last `\` you could use a pattern to match the leading char A-Z followed by `:\` and then optionally match until the last `\`

**Find what**

```
^[A-Z]:\\(?:.*\\)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]:\\` Match a single char A-Z and then `:\`
- `(?:.*\\)?` Optionally match the rest of the line until the last occurrence of `\`

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xc7nUW/1)

**Replace with**

Leave empty

[image]

---

If you want to remove the extension, and by that being the characters after the last dot, you can match what you want to remove and use a capture group for what you want to keep.

In the replacement use the capture group 1 value noted as `$1`

Assuming no `\` or `.` or spaces in the extension:

```
^[A-Z]:\\(?:.*\\)?([^\r\n\\]+)\.[^\\.\s]+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]:\\` Match a single char A-Z and then `:\`
- `(?:.*\\)?` Optionally match the rest of the line until the last occurrence of `\`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\r\n\\]+` Match 1+ chars other than newlines or `\`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\.[^\\.\s]+` Match `.` and 1+ chars other than `\` `.` or a whitespace char
- `$` End of string

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RF8I0x/1)

Comment: It's a nice explanation, slightly longer or more complex than mine. But I don't really understand the point of giving a second answer if someone already gave one 2 hours ago which does what the user needed. I personnaly thought "Oh, I have a bit of spare time and I didn't help someone on Stackoverflow for a while". @Mahan didn't really take the time to validate my answer or even try to find the solution to get rid of the file extensions. I finally gave him the full solution in my comment probably 4 minutes later. He didn't even answer it, so what's the point in giving another full solution?

Comment: @PatrickJanser That is an interesting comment, why not post another solution with a bit more specific pattern to match the example strings. Sometimes 5 or more answers are posted, which can also benefit future readers.

Comment: That's excelent. Thank you for the descriptions. :)